# Get Size Screen inside class Application and use other class

Tags: android

I want to get Size Screen in class Application.
I Create a class G the extends Application.

```
public class G  extends Application{

  private int Measuredwidth;

public int getSizeScreen()
   {
 WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
 final DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
return width;
 }
}
```

I do not know how to use it in a class(not Activity)
when I use below code

```
    public class Cricle extends View{
    // other code
   RADIUS=new G().getSizeScreen();
   }
```

give error:

```
   11-27 09:15:46.281: E/AndroidRuntime(19517): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   11-27 09:15:46.281: E/AndroidRuntime(19517): java.lang.NullPointerException
    11-27 09:15:46.281: E/AndroidRuntime(19517):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSystemService(ContextWrapper.java:416)
```

Comment: You cannot instantiate an Application with `new` and have it work properly. Your Application class must be specified in the manifest for it to be the current Application instance when your app is running.

Comment: how use methods inside G?

Comment: dont us getApplication() in Class View

Comment: If you mean you're getting that as a warning, yeah, you really shouldn't. That was merely an example of how to cast the Application. Create a setter method in your View class, and set the screen size from the Activity.

Comment: Thanks .I use a setter

Answer (score 0):

As in log:

> android.content.ContextWrapper.getSystemService(ContextWrapper.java:416)

Means `G` is not added in `<application />` tag.

When a class is extending `Application` class then to use that class also need to add in `AndroidManifest.xml` file inside `<application />`  using `android:name` attribute :

```
<application 
    android:name=".G">
  ...
</application>
```